# Simple utility maximization problem in a spatial equilibrium model

Tags: utility, supply-and-demand

I was going through the conceptual framework in the following paper

https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/shleifer/files/human_capital_qje_final.pdf

Gennaioli, N., La Porta, R., Lopez-de-Silanes, F., & Shleifer, A. (2013). Human capital and regional development. *Quarterly Journal of Economics*, 128(1), 105-164.

I don't understand how equation (8) in page 113 was derived.

According to the set up, an agent *j* maximizes

$$u(c,a)=c^{1-\theta_{j}}a^{\theta_{j}}$$

where $c$ and $a$ denote consumption and housing. The inelastic housing supply is equal to one, and the aggregate income of workers in region $i$ is $w_{i}H_{i}$. The price of consumption and the rent is 1 and $\eta_{i}$ respectivly.

Therfore, the budget constraint is $a\eta_{i}+c\leq w_{i}H_{i}$

By the standard property of the Cobb-Douglas utility function, the demand functions are given by

$$c=(1-\theta)w_{i}H_{i}$$

and

$$a\eta_{i}=\theta w_{i}H_{i}$$

I understand that the housing rental rate is given by equating unitary supply and housing demand so that $\eta_{i}=\theta w_{i} H_{i}$

But I don't see how we have

$$u_{w,i}(c,a)=\frac{w_{i}h}{\eta_{i}^{\theta}}$$

I thought that if we plug in the demand function back into the utility function, we should have

$$u_{w,i}(c,a)=((1-\theta)w_{i}h)^{1-\theta}(\frac{\theta w_{i}h}{\eta_{i}})^{\theta}=\frac{w_{i}h}{\eta_{i}^{\theta}}(1-\theta)^{1-\theta}\theta^{\theta}$$

In other words, $(1-\theta)^{1-\theta}\theta^{\theta}$ seems to have disappeared. Shouldn't we have "$\propto$" instead of "$=$" in the first part of (8)?